# Getting unique combinations, in order, from a list with non-uniques

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have an issue that I just can't wrap my head around and I'm hoping someone can help me out.

Imagine the following situation:

There is a list of people which all have a name. So each person is an object with the "name" property.  From that list, a random number of people is selected (so not all people are always in the selection) in random order, And each person is selected no more than once. However, names are potentially not unique: There might be more than one person in the list with the name "Smith". For this example, Let's imagine that each name is just one letter of the alphabet. So I might receive the following selection:

[V, C, R, C, F, X, R, C]

And the next time the selection might be completely different. Each element in that selection is a different person, But some of the names occur more than once.

Let's add numbers to clarify:

```
[V, C1, R1, C2, F, X, R2, C3]
```

Now I need all possible combinations of people where each name occurs only once, But respecting the sequence in which they were listed in the selection. Every unique name in the selection should be in the combination.
For instance, in this case I need:

```
[V, C1, R1, F, X],
[V, R1, C2, F, X],
[V, R1, F, X, C3],
[V, C1, F, X, R2],
[V, C2, F, X, R2]
...
```

And so on. People's positions should not be changed (i.e. [C1, V, ...] would not be ok because "V" should not come after "C1").

I'm assuming I will need recursivity and some way to keep track of the names, but that's where my brain starts to melt. ;-)  I have found scripts to get all possible permutations in any order, but nothing like this.

Could anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a conbination algorithm which takes an item (after a check if the same first letter is not in the temporary result set) for the result set or not and proceed with the next index until the wanted length is found or no more items are available.

```js
function getCombinations(array, size) {

    function fork(i, t) {
        if (t.length === size) {
            result.push(t);
            return;
        }
        if (i === array.length) {
            return;
        }
        if (!t.some(([c]) => c === array[i][0])) {
            fork(i + 1, t.concat([array[i]]));
        }
        fork(i + 1, t);
    }

    var result = [];
    fork(0, []);
    return result;
}

var data = ['V', 'C1', 'R1', 'C2', 'F', 'X', 'R2', 'C3'],
    result = getCombinations(data, 5);
 
console.log(result.map(a => a.join(' ')));
```

Comment: Sorry for the wait.  I tweaked a bit, but this one worked quite well. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple non-recursive algorithm.

```js
list = ['V', 'C1', 'R1', 'C2', 'F', 'X', 'R2', 'C3']; //

// build an index item => its positions
// (in your case item[0] == item.name)

let index = new Map;

for (let [i, item] of list.entries())
    index.set(item[0], (index.get(item[0]) || new Set).add(i));

// start with a single combination which is the initial list

let combs = [list];

// for each item and its positions...

for (let [item, is] of index) {

    // generate a new set of combinations

    let combs2 = [];

    // for each position...

    for (let i of is) {

        // all positions of this item, except of the current one

        let toRemove = new Set([...is]);
        toRemove.delete(i);

        // for all combinations... 

        for (let c of combs) {

            // insert null at these positions

            combs2.push(c.map((x, j) => toRemove.has(j) ? null : x));

        }
    }

    // continue with the new set of combinations

    combs = combs2;
}

// once we're ready remove all null values

combs = combs.map(c => c.filter(x => x !== null))

// done

for (let c of combs)
    console.log(c.join())
```